# how can i see the SQL generated by plpgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wrote a plpgsql function.
I want to see the exact SQL queries generated by it.

Any idea how can i do it?

Thanks,
Gil

Comment: Huh? plpsql pretty much *is* SQL. What is "generated"? Are you using `EXECUTE`? If so, you can report the query text you generate with `RAISE NOTICE` before you `EXECUTE` it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the contrib module [auto_explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html).

Load the module as described in the documentation and set the configuration parameters `auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on` and `auto_explain.log_min_duration = 0`.
**Warning:** This could cause a lot of log on a busy system, so better do it on a test system.

Then run your function, and the SQL statements executed inside the function (together with their execution plan) will be written to the server log.